# Trying to extract data

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am using VBA and extracting data from pages. I managed to extract a lot of data with " oIE.document.body.innerHTML"

However I encountered something where data visible on page is not present in this innerHTML. I found it while I inspected the exact spot On page. Below the screen shot. Is it possible to extract this kind of data with VBA? I am interested in data marked blue, exactly this rmbid number there.

#### Screenshot

[image: Code]

---

Ok.

I was extracting data from my company pages with

```
                link = "Page" 
                
                oIE.navigate link
                Do Until Not oIE.Busy And oIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
                HTMLsource = UCase(oIE.document.body.innerHTML)
```

And then I was using SPLIT function to get the data I need.
However in my newest project I encountered data which is visible on site but is not in this string I get with innerHTML method.
The string I get after innerHTML method:

> ```
> > <div id="mx_divTree"><div id="mx_divTreeHead"><table
> > id="treeHeadTable"><tr class="mx_hidden-row"><td id="ROW_1"
> > width="200"></td><td width="2"></td></tr><tr><th
> > id="Name"><table><tr><td height="25"><input
> > onclick="setCheckboxStatus(this)" name="chkList" class="small"
> > type="checkbox"></input></td><td id="Name" class="mx_sort-column"><a
> > href="javascript:sortTable(1)">Name</a></td><td
> > id="Name_sort"></td><td id="Name_filter"></td></tr></table></th><th
> > class="mx_sizer"></th></tr></table></div><div
> > id="mx_divTreeBody"><table><col class="mx_tree"></col></table>
> ```

However when I checked the page with "inspect element" in Mozzila  I found that the String above is missing data I need. But it is visible in the Inspect Element .

```
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="treeBodyTable" data-drag="Name" width="239"><tbody><tr class="mx_hidden-row"><td position="-1" width="1"></td><td id="ROW_1" width="238"></td></tr><tr id="0,0" o="20336.41905.55555.59004" r="" class="root-node 
                    even
                " style="height: 35px;" height="35"><td class="" position="-1"></td><td position="1" rownumber="1" rmbid="20336.41905.55555.59004" rmbrow="0,0" draggable="true"><div id="0,0" o="20336.41905.55555.59004" r="" t="" draggable="false"><table draggable="false"><tbody draggable="false"><tr id="0,0" o="20336.41905.55555.59004" r="" draggable="false"><td draggable="false"><input name="emxTableRowIdActual" class="small" id="rmbrow-0,0" value="|20336.41905.55555.59004||0,0" onclick="doFreezePaneCheckboxClick(this, event); doCheckSelectAll();" draggable="false" type="checkbox"></td><td id="icon_0,0" draggable="false"><a href="javascript:;" draggable="false"><img src="images/iconSmallPart.png" draggable="false"></a>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td><td title="80275509" position="1" rmbid="20336.41905.55555.59004" rmbrow="0,0" draggable="false" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:link(&quot;1&quot;,&quot;20336.41905.55555.59004&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;80275509&quot;)" data-oid="20336.41905.55555.59004" data-icon="images/iconSmallPart.png" class="object" draggable="false">80275509</a></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr><tr id="0,1" o="20336.41905.60930.27530" r="" class="root-node 
                    mx_altRow
                " style="height: 35px;" height="35"><td class="" position="-1"></td><td position="1" rownumber="1" rmbid="20336.41905.60930.27530" rmbrow="0,1" draggable="true"><div id="0,1" o="20336.41905.60930.27530" r="" t="" draggable="false"><table draggable="false"><tbody draggable="false"><tr id="0,1" o="20336.41905.60930.27530" r="" draggable="false"><td draggable="false"><input name="emxTableRowIdActual" class="small" id="rmbrow-0,1" value="|20336.41905.60930.27530||0,1" onclick="doFreezePaneCheckboxClick(this, event); doCheckSelectAll();" draggable="false" type="checkbox"></td><td id="icon_0,1" draggable="false"><a href="javascript:;" draggable="false"><img src="images/iconSmallPart.png" draggable="false"></a>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td><td title="80275509" position="1" rmbid="20336.41905.60930.27530" rmbrow="0,1" draggable="false" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:link(&quot;1&quot;,&quot;20336.41905.60930.27530&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;80275509&quot;)" data-oid="20336.41905.60930.27530" data-icon="images/iconSmallPart.png" class="object" draggable="false">80275509</a></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr><tr id="0,2" o="20336.41905.2564.37500" r="" class="root-node 
                    even
                " style="height: 33px;" height="33"><td class="" position="-1"></td><td position="1" rownumber="1" rmbid="20336.41905.2564.37500" rmbrow="0,2" draggable="true"><div id="0,2" o="20336.41905.2564.37500" r="" t="" draggable="false"><table draggable="false"><tbody draggable="false"><tr id="0,2" o="20336.41905.2564.37500" r="" draggable="false"><td draggable="false"><input name="emxTableRowIdActual" class="small" id="rmbrow-0,2" value="|20336.41905.2564.37500||0,2" onclick="doFreezePaneCheckboxClick(this, event); doCheckSelectAll();" draggable="false" type="checkbox"></td><td id="icon_0,2" draggable="false"><a href="javascript:;" draggable="false"><img src="images/fpc.gif" draggable="false"></a>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </td><td title="80275509" position="1" rmbid="20336.41905.2564.37500" rmbrow="0,2" draggable="false" valign="middle"><a href="javascript:link(&quot;1&quot;,&quot;20336.41905.2564.37500&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;80275509&quot;)" data-oid="20336.41905.2564.37500" data-icon="images/fpc.gif" class="object" draggable="false">80275509</a></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

So my question is: Is this possible to extract this "hidden" data with VBA?

Comment: please show what you've tried / used before, and explain why that doesn't work in this particular case. Also please include html as text instead of picture.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the information there, understanding code from comments is very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see this..

```
Set elements = doc.getElementsByid("0,0")
debug.Print = elements.innerHTML
```

declaring `elements` as an `object` should give you this (does it?)

EDIT (including the libraries):

[image]

Comment: Should I use ("0,0") as className or should I put something else? Because this method does not work as I get Error 438 while I try to print it.

Comment: @KamilG My mistake - it should be the `getElementsByid` - I've corrected my answer

Comment: Set elements = doc.getElementsByid("0,0")   - this line gives a 438 error.

Comment: Are you getting the error on the first of second line?

Comment: ...I can't believe I missed this... you have to declare `doc` as `object` too and declare it first (`Set doc = oIE.Document`). Sorry, should have noticed that

Comment: Well I figured that one myself, However I still get those errors.

Comment: What's the URL of the page and what is the website provide?

Comment: Well the page is only available from our company intranet. Maybe I dont have some library activated for that method? I tried debug.print doc.body.innerhtml and it worked perfectly however there is no data I am interested in. I think the real question is how to acces those hidden rows. Because I can see in the InnerHTML property that they are there, just their data is hidden.

Comment: Maybe... check my original answer with a screenshot of the libraries I have

Comment: Well that is not the case I have same libraries and even more activated.